# How to sort a text file into a list consisting of tuples and then appending to the list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, file, tuples

I'll try to be brief

Say I had a text file that looked like this:

```
Hassan
123
Tom
789
John
567
```

And I want to sort that into tuples in a list that looks like this:

```
scores = [('Hassan', '123'), ('Tom', '789'), ('John', '567')]
```

Then once I do that, I want to append the list with another tuple that has a similar format

Is there a simple way to get from a text file to a tuple array and then adding more tuples to the list?

Comment: Where do you take those extra tuples from that you want to append the list with once you've read the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you read the text from the file into the text variable you could split the text and iterate over the split tokens and group them into a list of tuples.

```
text = """
Hassan
123
Tom
789
John
567
"""
it = iter(text.split()))
scores = list(zip(it, it))
print(scores)
```

Output:

```
[('Hassan', '123'), ('Tom', '789'), ('John', '567')]
```

To append the list:

```
scores += [('Alex', '125')]
```

Comment: @HassanShahzad Another tuple? `scores += [(Alex, 125)]`

Comment: absolutely fantastic! Everything works. I appreciate it